# amsmath intlimits option doesn't work with STIX2 fonts when compiling usinf XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, amsmath, stix

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\[
    \int_{a}^{b}\qquad% doesn't work
    \int\displaylimits_{a}^{b}% works
\]
\end{document}
```

Can someone explain me why amsmath intlimits option doesn't want to work with STIX2Math font when compiling using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

At line 42 in amsmath.sty we have got

```
\DeclareOption{intlimits}{\let\ilimits@\displaylimits}
```

and at 628

```
\renewcommand{\int}{\DOTSI\intop\ilimits@}
```

so why only the second one of above in example codes works  as expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unicode-math` doesn't honor `amsmath` options referring to the placement of symbols, such as `nosumlimits` or `intlimits`, because all symbols are redefined.

You can use the (yet undocumented) feature `\removenolimits`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\removenolimits{\int\iint}

\begin{document}
\[
\int_{a}^{b} \iint_a^b
\]
\end{document}
```

In the argument to `\removenolimits` you should list all commands that should be affected.

[image]

Actually the `unicode-math` way is more flexible, because it allows to use `\displaylimits` for `\iint` but not for `\int`.

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/497